# Costs of commercial vs open source

Tags: commercial, project-management, finance

I am comparing two types of products, a commercial product and a commercially supported opensource product and comparing the cost over a certain period.

The commercial product cost includes maintenance fees, disaster recovery site, CPU costs, cost/user. The open source product only has subscriptions fees according to CPU and users.

It is worth knowing that both of these products package-based/'off the shelf', but are two different categories of it. Maintenance fees could be referred to as OPEX costs.

What additional costs should I take into consideration to work out with more precision the cost over a time period?

e.g  hardware cost for the production and disaster environments- since two products have different hardware needs as variations of application users

A very similar definition to the open source package can be found here 
http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/8/96615-seven-principles-for-selecting-software-packages/fulltext

Comment: The open source product should be free. Or else this is not FOSS!

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne what? FOSS doesn’t necessarily imply cost-free, as you surely know — see [GNU’s page on the matter](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html) for example.

Comment: Open source != free download. But very likely free.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that this is the 'definition' given to the commercially supported open source product.

Comment: I think this question is asking about what factors apply when computing [total cost of ownership](http://www.cio.com/article/3005705/software/calculating-the-total-cost-of-ownership-for-enterprise-software.html) for open source software. TCO includes time your corporate help desk has to spend on support, cost of hardware, etc. However, I don't know how this is different for proprietary versus open software (but I guess it's still a fair question, even if the answer is, "there is no difference in how to evaluate TCO for open source software")

Comment: @StephenKitt While open source software can have a nonzero purchase price, it is weird that the open source version has... subscription fees? ("*The open source product only has subscriptions fees according to CPU and users.*") OP, what happens if you don't pay the subscription fees? If the answer is, "you lose your right to possess or run the software," then this is certainly not open source. If the answer is, "you lose official support from the vendor," then you should make the clearer in the question.

Comment: @apsillers my salary is paid for by companies buying subscriptions for open source, it’s not that weird ;-).

Comment: The background question is which option is cost-effective, but I was asked to look at what other factors (apart from the costs outlined) could also contribute towards working out the best cost-effective solution.

Comment: @StephenKitt re "The open source product should be free. Or else this is not FOSS!" .... my point about it being free is that if the open source software is only ever available commercially and never as #FOSS then this is not FOSS. I meant free as in some minimal freedom and #DFSG. e.g. there needs to be some open sourcing taking place either publicly or to to the commercial customers, under some FOSS license for it to be ever considered as open source.

Comment: @Hawwa can you update your question with links to the actual alternative you are considering? Otherwise this is all very theoretical and therefore hard for any of us to provide some feedback and answer.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne The definitions were just given to me, but this link seems to have a similar definition  http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/8/96615-seven-principles-for-selecting-software-packages/fulltext

Comment: For me I cannot provide an answer to your question that I found is not specific enough.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne OK, free as in libre, sorry for the confusion. I thought you were reacting to the fees associated with the software!